# How to handle run time error 424 when website search fails?

Tags: excel, vba

I track consignment numbers from tracking courier website in IE.

A few consignment numbers do not have details from which it throws out a message

> "Invalid AWB No. Please try again later."

When my code stops execution by giving run time error 424.

How do I skip and move to next item search?

```vb
Sub CountryPopList()
    'declare the variables
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement
    Dim i As Integer
        
    'create and get access to an instance of IE
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
        
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    With ieObj
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://shipway.in/rivigo_courier"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
        
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        
        'in the search box put cell "A2" value
        ieObj.document.getElementById("waybill").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
        
        'click the 'go' button
        ieObj.document.getElementsByName("submit")(0).Click
        
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("shp_table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).Children(1).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("shp_table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("shp_table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(5).Children(1).textContent
        End With
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is an example valid search value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a valid code to test with I will tighten this up. You can use a timed loop to wait for the results table to be present  (I in fact wait for the first td cell so I can re-use the variable I hold this in later). Then check if the first table cell contains the text `Invalid AWB`. Only if that is not present execute the lines of code within the If statement.

Generally, I would read all search values in from sheet initially, into an array, then loop the array and perform your searches. Store results in an array and write that array out in one go at end.

Furthermore, I would use an explicit sheet name in place of `Activesheet`. I don't know whether you intend to overwrite `Sheet1`, but it is a possibility when using `Activesheet`; if `Sheet1` is currently active.

I've used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to re-write some of your element selection. This method applies [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to match on elements. It is faster and more flexible. Again, with a valid search value I can test and ensure indexing and syntax is correct. You can always substitute your original code lines back in that section.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountryPopList()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer, htmlEle As IHTMLElement, t As Date, td As IHTMLTableCell
    Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement, i As Long, lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ieObj
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://shipway.in/rivigo_courier"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        For i = 2 To lastRow

            .document.getElementById("waybill").Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
            .document.querySelector("[name=submit]").Click
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set td = .document.querySelector(".shp_table td")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While td Is Nothing
            If Not td Is Nothing Then
                If Not InStr(td.innerText, "Invalid AWB") > 0 Then
                    With ActiveSheet             '<= should probably use an explicit sheet here or could overwrite Sheet1. Also, bug prone.
                        .Range("A" & i).Value = .document.querySelector(".shp_table tr:nth-of-type(1) td").textContent 'verify correct when provided working search code
                        .Range("B" & i).Value = .document.querySelector(".shp_table tr:nth-of-type(2) td").textContent
                        .Range("C" & i).Value = .document.querySelector(".shp_table tr:nth-of-type(5) td").textContent
                    End With
                End If
            End If
            Set td = Nothing
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is working fine. I have done a small modification and everything else in terms of error handling your code piece works fine. :-)