# Web Scraping: Button clicking and help navigating through paths

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to scrape some doctor names and addresses from the website: https://albertafindadoctor.ca/find-a-doc/directory

I am trying to solve the following issue:

1. Once on the doctor's toggle, I want to pull 4 pieces of data from the entire page, not just the first 25 displayed.

While the code works for the initial webpage, it only pulls the first 25 pieces of data. There are a significant number of other pages that I still need to pull (3822 different doctors).

Unfortunately, I'm at a loss on how to navigate and pull from these different pages. When I inspect elements to see how to navigate between pages a see matrix changing so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it?

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAlbertaDoctors()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim clinicEle As Object

    Dim clinicName As String
    Dim clinicAddress As String
    Dim clinicCategory As String
    Dim doctorName As String

    Dim y As Integer

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.Navigate "https://albertafindadoctor.ca/find-a-doc/directory"
    While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
    objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("physician-toggle")(0).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

    y = 2

    For Each clinicEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("clinic")
        clinicCategory = clinicEle.getElementsByClassName("pcn")(0).innerText
        clinicName = clinicEle.getElementsByClassName("clinic-name")(0).innerText
        doctorName = clinicEle.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
        clinicAddress = clinicEle.getElementsByClassName("address")(0).innerText

        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & y).Value = clinicCategory
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & y).Value = clinicName
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & y).Value = doctorName
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & y).Value = clinicAddress

        y = y + 1
    Next

    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set" on the clicking line:

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("physician-toggle active")(0).Click
```

Comment: Either `getElementsByClassName` returns `Nothing` and the implicit `.Item(0)` call is going against `Nothing`, or the implicit `.Item(0)` call yields `Nothing` and the `.Click` call is going against `Nothing`. In either case, that code is doing way too many things and has too many reasons to fail. Break it down into smaller instructions, and **validate** the object references aren't `Nothing` before you make a member call.

Comment: Could be that `Document` is `Nothing`, too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually realized that the button should be `objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("physician-toggle")(0).Click` and not `objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("physician-toggle active")(0).Click`  When you say too many reasons to fial what are you referring to? I'm a beginner so I'm curious about mistakes I'm making. Thanks!

Comment: I'm referring to the chained member calls, each assuming the previous was successful. That said I'm not blaming you for it - these chained member calls are everywhere in docs, blogs, and SO answers. `Dim physicianToggleButton As Object` and go `Set physicianToggleButton = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("physician-toggle")` and then `If Not physicianToggleButton Is Nothing Then physicianToggleButton(0).Click` (else debug.print "could not find element blablabla"), i.e. break things down, validate that you're getting a valid object reference before you make a member call against it.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop all pages. You can use the browser to get to that page and click on `Doctors` if required. After that, grab the number of results and then mimic the [xhr request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) the page makes for listings - which is returned as json. Alter the query string the page makes i.e. the parameter for limit to get all listings. Use a json parser (I use jsonconverter - instructions in the code for installation) to parse out your info.

There is a proper page load wait and a couple of loops to ensure elements are present. These should really be timed loops. See loop format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57350051/6241235).

I add an additional test to ensure you do not attempt to click `Doctors` when it is not required to do so.

Not all listings has all info hence the `On Error Resume Next` paired with `On Error GoTo 0`. Looks like you may be able to build a dictionary to fill in some of the blank values based on existing paired values (or using ids present in json object).

I store all results in an array and write out in one go.

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
' Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Download and add to standard module called jsonconverter from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas
Public Sub GetListings()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, s As String, json As Object, newUrl As String

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://albertafindadoctor.ca/find-a-doc/directory"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.querySelector("[data-cp-option=physician]")
            If Not .className = "physician-toggle active" Then .Click
        End With

        Dim resultsInfo() As String, numResults As Long, ele As Object

        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector(".paginator")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        Do
        Loop While .document.querySelector(".paginator").innerText = vbNullString

        resultsInfo = Split(Trim$(.document.querySelector(".paginator").innerText), "of ")

        .Quit
    End With

    numResults = resultsInfo(UBound(resultsInfo))
    newUrl = "https://albertafindadoctor.ca/search/directory/physicians?page=1&limit=" & numResults & "&with[]=pcn&with[]=clinics&with[]=languages&with[]=specialties"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", newUrl, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("items")     
    End With

    Dim row As Object, results(), r As Long, headers(), ws As Worksheet, key As Variant

    headers = Array("clinicCategory", "clinicName", "doctorName", "clinicAddress")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ReDim results(1 To json.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For Each row In json
        r = r + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each key In row.keys
            Select Case key
                Case "clinical_name"
                    results(r, 3) = row(key)
                Case "pcn"
                    results(r, 1) = row(key)("name")
                Case "clinics"
                    results(r, 2) = row(key)(1)("name")
                    results(r, 4) = Join$(Array(row(key)(1)("street_address"), row(key)(1)("city"), row(key)(1)("province"), row(key)(1)("postal_code")), ", ")
            End Select
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

---

Reading:

1. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
2. [json](https://www.json.org/)
3. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
4. [arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm) and [arrays2](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for this. This was able to pull incredibly quickly but didn't pull everything for some reason. I still need to dig deeper into why this is. There are a lot of functions here I don't completely understand yet

Comment: Can you give me an example of what wasn't pulled back please? Be specific as possible so I can re-create. As for stuff you don't undertand - ask away :-)

Comment: For me, it is only pulling about 1/3 of the doctors. I've tried to recreate my issue but now I'm getting a run time error 13 on the following line:  `numResults = resultsInfo(UBound(resultsInfo))` Also sorry for my late response I have been out of the country

Comment: Which line is that?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to reference lines, but its the 36th line after option explicit.

Comment: You could just paste the line here in comment

Comment: `numResults = resultsInfo(UBound(resultsInfo))` Gives me runtime error 13

Comment: before that line add the line _debug.print .document.querySelector(".paginator").innerText_

Comment: Sorry, I get a compile error when I try to do that, invalid or unqualified unique reference. I might be being dense on this one

Comment: Put ie in front of the dot